# How to change exit code message of bash

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, continuous-integration, azure-devops

I have a CI CD pipeline where I use a bash task to execute some script.
I want the build to fail if the script fails. So now I implemented an exit code where the bash script needs to fail. All good except for the error message.

[image: Bash exited with code 2]

I want to use a exit code whereby I can set an error message something like:

```
exit "script failed because alerts were found"
```

But I found online that you can only pass integers to your exit code.
Tried to fix it with:

```
echo "fail message"
exit code 2
```

But on my pipeline I got the `Bash exited with code '2'.` message and after i open the task output i can see my echo message.
Don't know if this is a Azure DevOps issue or I can fix this in bash. Anyone has any ideas?

[EDIT] Tried it with trap inside my local machine, and the custom error message works. But the same thing didn't work in Azure DevOps. I might think this is not possible in Azure DevOps -_-. Is there someone who already tried this ?

Comment: Your CI/CD toolchain is not showing any script output here, it *only* shows the integer return code given by the script. I would suspect any output is logged somewhere else. So you need to be looking to your CI/CD toolchain for solutions, not your bash script.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you have a look at "trap" command :
https://www.shellscript.sh/trap.html

and try something like :

```
trap 'your_function' EXIT
```

Comment: Trap Documentation: https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the console in the screenshot shows only the script's standard error?

I would try something like:

```
echo "fail message" 1>&2
exit code 2
```

Comment: perhaps , Azure DevOps indeed only shows standard erros that's what i was hoping for that can maybe be customable.
Your code will definitely work inside a not 'ci/cd pipeline build' but in this case it maybe possible that this can onle be fixed :(